# Subtype with different parameter than supertype

Tags: julia, subtype

Let's say I have defined a Type merely as a alias for a certain array in `Julia` but with additional information, let's say just a string

```
abstract A{T,N}
   foo::AbstractArray{T,N}
   bar::Real
end
```

I would like to define a Subtype having maybe another element but also restricting the second parameter of the type to be an integer and having a value of `N+1` if `B` is of type `N`.

```
type B{N::Int} <: A{T,N+1}
   baz::Float64
end
```

In this example neither `::Int` nor `N+1` seem to be right nor are they syntactically. I'm a little new to Julia but I read a lot the last days and couldn't find a solution for that.

How can I do such a “restricted” subtype?

*Edit*: Maybe there's even another glitch. For the supertype N should be able to be a vector specifying the size of `foo` while for the subtype it should be an integer specifying the length of the vector.

*Edit 2*: I meant to use an `abstract A` which I edited now as mentioned in the comments

*Edit 3*: So I think one problem seems to be, that `abstract` types can not have fields (which I don't understand why but anyhow), then still I can't declare Type parameters to be e.g. just an Integer.
So how can I do something like

```
abstract A{T,N}
type B{N::Integer} <: A{Float64,N+1}
  v:FixedVector{N+1,Float64}
end
```

I always get the problem, that `N` always (no matter what I do) stays a Typevar while I would like to just have an Integer. So is there a way to make a type dependent on a variable?

Comment: Lots of issues here, but perhaps the biggest one is that you can only subtype abstract types. http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/types/

Comment: Thanks for the first reply. Well I'm still learning to understand subtyping. You'Re right, it was a little late yesterday, of course I meant to write `abstract A`. I edited that. And yes I spend hours on that page yesterday.

Comment: Your last question (edit 3) is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551571/julia-instantiated-type-parameters.